# Iteration with creating a new DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom, optimization, iteration

I have a problem on high load iteration.

```
CommonMethods.showLoader();

var html = $("<div>");

for (var i = 0, length = folder.tracks.length; i < length; i++) {            
    var clone = Track.create(folder.tracks[i], folder.folder_id);
    html.append(clone.show());
}      

$tracks.html(html);
CommonMethods.hideLoader();
```

Track.create method creates a DOM element and sets the attributes, also returns a jquery element.

My `folder.tracks` array has approx 3000 tracks, so the script creates approx 3000 DOM elements before adding to the page.

`CommonMethods.showLoader` - shows the loader while new elements are creating
`CommonMethods.hideLoader` - removes the loader.

The problem that the loader is not showing up. I tried to log his appearance but log works perfect, loader log that he shows himself before the iteration. If I delete `hideLoader` method then the loader is showing up after the DOM elements created and added to the page. But console.log shows that he shows up before the iteration. How to handle this problem?

**UPDATE**: my showLoader function

```
    showLoader: function() {

        console.log("loader was showed");

        $(".loader").show();
    },
```

**UPDATE2**

example : https://jsfiddle.net/70b3x2uo/5/

Comment: Show us the `showLoader()` function

Comment: @Rajesh no, it doesn't matter, my variant is shorter)

Comment: @Rajesh just tried as an experiment but didn't work. I think that show() is applying before append and return the jquery element, so it doesn't matter when you use it

Comment: @Rajesh sorry I didn't say that Track.create returns a jquery element

Comment: @socm_ ok this is little hacky but works https://jsfiddle.net/70ec8ddn/ I did it with the help of setTimeout()

Comment: @sand I did the same thing, but thanks for the answer, you can post as answer, MB for somebody it will be helpful